# Inference in probabilistic graphical models (Bayesian networks)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem, bayesian-network

I've been given a practice final exam that uses [this network from CMU](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/learn-43/lib/photoz/.g/web/glossary/bayesnet.html) and was given some probabilities to determine. I'll attach some pictures below of the information at the link above.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've been able to solve all of the questions so far with the exception of two:

$P(C=1 | R=1, H=1, M=0)$

$P(M=1 | H=1, C=0)$

---

When I initially see these, I look at the graph and notice that $C$ and $M$ don't depend on anything ($M$ depends on $V$ but $V$ is not in the question), so I keep thinking they're just $P(C=1)$ and $P(M=1)$. I feel like I'm missing something and would appreciate a push in the right direction! I assume I will need something like Bayes' rule, total probability, conditional probability, etc.

---

**edit:** The graphical model contains conditional independence relationships. The assumptions needed to answer the questions are:

$P(h|r,c,m) = P(h|c,m)$

$P(m|c) = P(m)$

$P(c|m) = P(c)$

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about message passing in a Bayesian network?  The fact that C doesn't have any direct dependencies doesn't mean you can't reason about it.  C is a parent node of R and H.  That is what the arrow represents.  The question $P(C=1|....)$ is stating that you have an observation on $R, H, \text{and } M$ and want to know the probability that $C=1$ given that observation.

To do so depends on the message passing scheme you are using and usually involves a multi-way distribution of information, first from the observations, to all unknown nodes, then a unification of belief in the network.  What message passing scheme are you using?  It will help you here.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. This is the last topic of the course so we're kind of still learning it right now. Haven't heard anything about "message passing schemes". The information in the OP is pretty much all there is, with the exception of one little part which I just edited in. Does that help at all?

Comment: Not...really :-P At least, not for me, perhaps someone more skilled in BNs would know.  How have you been incorporating observations to update probabilities so far?

Comment: The other questions were more trivial. Pretty much warmed up with ones that can be taken straight from the tables, then some simple Bayes' rules ones and other stuff like that. It's getting more tricky when there are 3 and 4 variables now.